# How to backup file to iCloud but not shown in iCloud Drive?

Tags: swift, icloud, icloud-drive

I'm backup my database realm file to iCloud by using `FileManage` methods. Everything works fine, but there's a trick I want to achieve is:

`The file should be backup by iCloud, but NOT shown in iCloud Drive.`

For example, GoodNotes 5, we can open the iCloud in settings, verify it's truly backup in iCloud Storage, and the GoodNots 5 App File is not shown in iCloud Drive.
[image]

Below is my code that implement iCloud backup, but the App File `ama` will be shown in iCloud Drive:

```
private func retrieveLocalRealmURL() -> URL {
    let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentaryDirectory = urls[0]
    let realmURL = documentaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("ama.realm");
    
    return realmURL
}

private func backupRealmToiCloudDrive() {
    let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
    
    backgroundQueue.async {
        guard
            let ubiquityURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)
        else {
            return
        }
            
        let iCloudDriveURL = ubiquityURL.appendingPathComponent("Documents")
        let iCloudRealmURL = iCloudDriveURL.appendingPathComponent("ama.realm")
        
        let fileExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: iCloudDriveURL.path, isDirectory: nil)
        
        func copy() {
            let localRealmURL = self.retrieveLocalRealmURL()
            
            do {
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: localRealmURL, to: iCloudRealmURL)
            } catch {
                printLog(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        
        if fileExists {
            self.deleteExistedFile(iCloudRealmURL)
            copy()
        } else {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: iCloudDriveURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                copy()
            } catch {
                printLog(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}

private func deleteExistedFile(_ url: URL) {
    let fileCoordinator = NSFileCoordinator(filePresenter: nil)
    
    fileCoordinator.coordinate(writingItemAt: url, options: .forDeleting, error: nil) { deleteURL in
        do {
            let fileExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: deleteURL.path, isDirectory: nil)
            
            if fileExists {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: deleteURL)
            }
        } catch {
            printLog(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: hi @Andres, yes, it's solved, pls see my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

After many tests, to avoid backup file to iCloud Drive, but in iCloud container, you can just simply remove the 'Documents' path, but using file path directly, like below:

```
let ubiquityURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: "identifier.abcdefg")

let iCloudDriveURL = ubiquityURL.appendingPathComponent("Documents") //remove this line
let iCloudRealmURL = iCloudDriveURL.appendingPathComponent("ama.realm")
```

change to:

```
let iCloudRealmURL = ubiquityURL.appendingPathComponent("ama.realm") //appending to ubiquityURL directly
```

In this case, the backup file will be stored in iCloud container, but not shown in the user's iCloud Drive.